# How to add variable to mapToGroups in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query :

```
$options = $product->options->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
  return [$item->group->type => $item];
});
```

It returns my product options with with their group types,

#### Overview

`dd code above`

```
Collection {#3138 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "color" => Collection {#3132 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    "dropdown" => Collection {#3133 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    "radio" => Collection {#3134 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you see this product options are grouped in 3 types `color, dropdown & radio`

Till this step everything is OK but I also need to get those group `Titles` in order to show the title above each group of options.

## Screenshot

[image: one]

## Code

`Controller`

```
$options = $product->options->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
  return [$item->group->type => $item];
});
```

`Blade`

```
@foreach($options as $group => $option)
  @if($group == 'color')
    {{$group}}: //group type (must replace with group title)
    @foreach($option as $opt) //looping options
      <option>{{$opt->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
  @elseif($group == 'dropdown')
    // same loop as above happens here...
  @else
    // same loop as above happens here...
  @endif
@endforeach
```

#### Note:

As my group types are fixed `Only color,dropdown & radio` so I will need this type for my loops `if conditions` I just need to somehow add their titles in my query because titles are dynamic can be anything.

### more...

`Example` I can have dropdown option with title `color` as well as `size` or anything else so my type is same `dropdown` but titles and options under that are different.

## Question

1. How to place my option groups title in my query?

*PS: in case you need more code please let me know I will share.*

## Update

Here is the structure of my products options and where titles and data comes from:

`Product Model`

```
public function options(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class, 'product_options', 'product_id', 'option_id');
}
```

`Option Model`  This is my product options

```
public function group(){
  return $this->belongsTo(OptionGroup::class, 'option_id');
}

public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

`OptionGroup Model` this is where titles of each option groups come from

```
public function values(){
  return $this->hasMany(Option::class, 'option_id');
}
```

The models above behave like this:

```
Option Group = Color
Option = Red, Blue, Yellow (under color)
Product = Color->[red, blue, yellow]
```

## Update 2

```
Collection {#3221 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "color" => Collection {#3215 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Option {#2859 ▼
          +timestamps: false
          #fillable: array:7 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "options"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:7 [▶]
          #original: array:9 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: array:2 [▼
            "pivot" => Pivot {#2869 ▶}
            "group" => OptionGroup {#2922 ▼
              +timestamps: false
              #fillable: array:2 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: "option_groups"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:3 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "title" => "COLORS"
                "type" => "color"
              ]
              #original: array:3 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
          #touches: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
        1 => Option {#2860 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "dropdown" => Collection {#3216 ▶}
    "radio" => Collection {#3217 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: There's some context missing here...  It sounds like the title is supposed to be coming from another table/model, is this correct?  Can you paste the model in charge of fetching the title?  Can you also paste a description of the table it's pulling from?

Comment: Are you using laravel's language system for titles or they come with the data? Where are your `Title`'s ?

Comment: @MichaelMiller yes there is another table involved i will update my question

Comment: @TahaPaksu Yes it's laravel, and titles coming from database (dynamic inputs)

Comment: @mafortis, as a final debugging step, can you post what's printed to the screen if you add dd($options) right after your mapToGroups logic in your controller?  My gut tells me the data is there for you to pull.  I just can't visualize the outcome of that logic.

Comment: @MichaelMiller the output of options i published at the top of my question that is what i get, 1. Type of option groups 2. Each option of that type under it but not the title

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I'd like to see one of the child elements of #items.  It looks like the child elements under each of these could hold your title.

Comment: @MichaelMiller updated, please see `relations` part.

Comment: So this next step should answer my question...  Can you take this one step further and extend "attributes?". I'm expecting to see a title in there.

Comment: @MichaelMiller i already extend it, there is a title the but we have a issue, items loop is around li tags while we need title out of their loop at the top

Comment: Relations->groups->attributes

Comment: @MichaelMiller any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

With `$opt->group->title` i'm now able to get group titles.

The only trick here is that I MUST loop first my `$opt` in order to avoid multiple titles as they come with my options (see update 2 relations).

```
@foreach($option as $opt)
  @if($loop->first)
    {{$opt->group->title}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
@foreach($options as $group => $option)
  @if($group == 'color')
    {{$option->group->title}}: //group type (must replace with group title)
    @foreach($option as $opt) //looping options
      <option>{{$opt->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
  @elseif($group == 'dropdown')
    // same loop as above happens here...
  @else
    // same loop as above happens here...
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: No man this gets all option groups and their childs I only need each product options.

Comment: i'm afraid not, `the reason is` I don't really get groups data from the group all i get is the type name `color, dropdown etc.` if I was getting array of groups then I would be able to get `title, id, etc.` but as long as I just return `type` i don't have access to other columns of my groups. **Sample** `"color" => Collection {#3132 ▼` this only gets type column of my groups nothing more.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...  Can you help me understand where my logic breaks down?  In the dump above, your top level is a collection of options.  The items under that are an associative array of groups ("color", "dropdown", and "radio").  Those groups contain an array of Option objects.  The Option object contains an association with the OptionGroup class.  This class contains a "title" attribute.  Are you getting an error when you try to print the title using that method?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: that returns error but with `$opt->group->title` i'm now able to get group titles :) the only trick here is that I MUST loop first my $opt in order to avoid multiple titles. `@foreach($option as $opt) @if($loop->first) {{$opt->group->title}} @endif @endforeach`